# My external monitor not fitting full screen - samsung

Tags: display, hdmi, resolution

It is my first question here so sorry if everything is clear.

**My problem**: I bought an external monitor SAMSUNG LS24R350FHUXEN [LINK]1920x1080.(https://www.samsung.com/uk/monitors/monitor-sr350/). When I connect monitor to MBP is not fitting whole screen - image below. Of course I tried to fix that by setting resolution with option + scaled in system preference, but the closest resolution is 1080p. Don't have 1920x1080, only 1600x900, 1080p, 720p etc but not 1920x1080. I connect with HDMI 2.0 but also tried to fix that by connect with hdmi supplied with monitor, but this is no problem with hdmi. With my mom's windows laptop is everything ok. I think that is problem with MBP or my connection with MBP.
Connection: MONITOR -> HDMI -> GREEN CELL HUB -> MBP (USB-C).

My MBP : MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports).

[image]

Please help me, I have been trying to fix that for 4 hours and still can't.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this help ? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/149149/issues-with-screen-scaling-on-external-monitor/149152#149152

Comment: I tried to do that I said it in my problem description. Its not working.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of system preferences > Display Preferences on your external monitor?

Comment: I added 2 images to the main post. Sorry that is in Polish but I think everything is easy to understand.